# Postfix to Infix with minimum number of parentheses

Tags: java, infix-notation, postfix-notation

I am looking for algorithm postfix to infix notation which will produce the minimum number of the parentheses.

I have found that but it will produce many, many parentheses: http://tajendrasengar.blogspot.com/2011/09/postfix-to-infix-algorithm.html

**For example**

The input:

```
<ONP>abcd*/+~
```

The result:

```
<INF>~(a+b/(c*d))
```

Comment: Why? What do you care how many parentheses there are?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need to do if you really want as few parentheses as possible, is similar to what the algorithm you linked to says. However...

- You should store an operator for each *composite* operand in the `Stack`. Namely, the last operator used in the operand. You could use a second `Stack` for this. If the operand is not composite, you could add `null` to the second `Stack`, since there is no operator.
- Don't encapsulate the resulted `String` with parentheses. That is done elsewhere in the algorithm (see below).

When you pop the top two values from each of the `Stack`s, you have 3 operators at hand:

- The current operator
- The last used operator in the first operand (if the operator exists)
- The last used operator in the second operand (if the operator exists)

Depending on these three operators, you should encapsulate the first and/or second operand with parentheses, before combining them.

You could use operator precedence to determine whether there should be parentheses. The order goes like this: `(none), {"*", "/"}, {"+", "-"}`

- The first operand needs parentheses if and only if its operator has a lower precedence than the current operator.
- The second operand needs parentheses if its operator has a lower precedence than the current operator, or if they have equal precedence where the current operator is either `"/"` or `"-"`.

The rest should be done the way your algorithm described.

Comment: What about operator precedence?

Answer (score 0):

I found an example to solve this problem. There is a _Unparsing class in [ast](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/ast.py#L684) library of python to unparse AST tree.

There is a require_parens function in the library to check parentheses.

Example:

```
~% python3.11
>>> import ast
>>> ast.unparse(ast.parse("(-(-1+2)+((2*3))-4)"))
'-(-1 + 2) + 2 * 3 - 4'
>>>
```

If you want you can convert AST tree to postfix notation using a ast.walk function. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590512/how-to-convert-from-infix-to-postfix-prefix-using-ast-python-module)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the implementation:

```
public class PostfixToInfixConverter implements ExpressionConverter {

@Override
public String convert(String postfix) {
    String[] expressions = postfix.split("\\s");
     Deque<Expression> stack = new LinkedList<Expression>();
    for (String exp : expressions) {
        if (exp.equals("+") || exp.equals("-")) {
            String right = stack.pop().getExpression();
            String left = stack.pop().getExpression();
            Expression newExp = new Expression(right + exp + left, exp);
            stack.push(newExp);
        } else if (exp.equals("*") || exp.equals("/")) {
            String right = correctExpression(stack.pop());
            String left = correctExpression(stack.pop());
            stack.push(new Expression(right +  exp +  left, exp));
        } else {
            stack.push(new Expression(exp, ""));
        }
    }
    return stack.pop().getExpression();
}

private String correctExpression(Expression exp) {
    String result = exp.getExpression();
    if (exp.getOperatorUsed().equals("+") || exp.getOperatorUsed().equals("-")) {
        result = "(" + result + ")";
    }
    return result;
}

private static class Expression {
    String expression;
    String operatorUsed;
    public Expression(String exp, String operator) {
        this.expression = exp;
        this.operatorUsed = operator;
    }
    public String getExpression() {
        return expression;
    }
    public String getOperatorUsed() {
        return operatorUsed;
    }       
}
```

}

Here is the unit tests

```
@Test
public void test() {
    ExpressionConverter converter = new PostfixToInfixConverter();
    assertThat(converter.convert("1 2 * 3 4 * + 5 *"), equalTo("5*(4*3+2*1)"));
    assertThat(converter.convert("a b + c + 2 *"), equalTo("2*(c+b+a)"));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't minimise parentheses.